# SQL Server Linked Server failed login

Tags: sql-server, authentication, linked-server

On Server A (SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition), I'm trying to create a Linked Server to Server B (SQL Server 2016 Enterprise), but this returns the error below.  I'm connect with my Windows account on sysadmin on both servers.  I can create a Linked Server to both servers from my local client.  I don't have any OS permission.

- The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?
- Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Server A is mixed mode authentication, and Server B is Windows.  It's probably not an option to change Server B (and the other target servers) to mixed mode authentication.   I was able to create a Linked Server on Server B pointing to Server A with a SQL login on Server A. However, we need to connection in the opposite direction.

I've tried the OLEDB Provider for SQL Server option, which returns "Login timeout expired".

Also, I've tired the various Security tab options: login mapping, login's current security context, and "be made using this security context" with my sysadmin Windows account.  All of these options fail with error messages.  The login mapping returns the error  "Login timeout expired".

- Do Linked Servers require any sort of OS permission?
- Is there a way to create Linked Servers?

Thanks,

Conrad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server Linked Server Issue "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180127/sql-server-linked-server-issue-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-lo)

Comment: To a certain extent, this is related to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245434/bulk-insert-returns-error-access-is-denied. You first need to provision a proper service account, assign it to SQL Server (and SQL Agent), then give that service account all required access. This _might_ solve this problem but will save you a lot of other problems also

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but thought I'd document a solution which I found at the below link.

The fix:

1. on the 'New Linked Server' dialog, select the 'Security' page.
2. on the Security page, select one of the **bottom two** radio buttons ('...using the login's current security...', or '...using this security context...')

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/06/11/sql-server-fix-linked-server-error-7399-invalid-authorization-specification/