# BULK INSERT returns error "Access is denied"

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

When running Bulk Insert

```
BULK INSERT MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable 
FROM '\\Mylaptop\UniversalShare\SQLRuleOutput.csv' 
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

on a remote SQL Server I get this error:

> "Cannot bulk load because the file
>   "\MyLaptop\UniversalShare\SQLRuleOutput.csv" could not be opened.
>   Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)."

- The share is open to all.
- I have run PowerShell `Invoke-SQLCMD` scripts on that SQL Server that where it connects to that same share, so the server can see the share.
- This `Bulk Insert` statement fails with the same error whether I run it directly as T-SQL on the SQL Server, or through PowerShell `Invoke-SQLCMD` (which is my intended method).

This question is similar, [Cannot bulk load. Operating system error code 5 (Access is denied.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555262/cannot-bulk-load-operating-system-error-code-5-access-is-denied), but in my case the share is open to all, so permissions *shouldn't* be an issue, and the share is definitely in a different place (my laptop for POC development) than SQL Server.

Does anyone know why this error is happening, or how to get around it?

Thanks,

Conrad

Comment: PS:  If I script out all the data as Insert statements, then that SQL Server imports all the data correctly, but my source data is in .csv format.

Answer (score 3):

The share must be accessible to the Windows account that the MSSQL Service is running under; typically Local System or Network Service (but could be anything). Its unlikely you have explcitly granted access to MYSERVER\LOCAL SERVICE to your local file share.

Running Powershell Invoke-SQLCMD doesn't demonstrate that the MSSQL service has rights to your drive - it depends what account you are running power shell as.

Comment: The share is read/write for everyone. The SQL Server is running under "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER".  Do I need to, and is there any way to explicitly add that NT Service account to have read/write permission on a share?

Comment: That account is unlikely to have access as it's not a domain account. Don't give it access. The correct approach is to create a proper service account and use that instead. Are you using active directory? If not, it's difficult to manage these permission issues properly.

Comment: Execute As (myself) returns the same error of "Access is denied", so Bulk Insert only runs as the service account. The TSQL and PowerShell statements I ran as myself.

In this case, we can't change that service account, so my workaround will likely have to be to generate a series of Insert Into statements.  It's not too much data to do that.

Comment: @ConradS., you could use SqlBulkCopy from your PowerShell script instead of a T-SQL BULK INSERT so that the client processes the file instead of the database engine. That will be a but faster than individual Inserts.

Comment: A better solution would be to open up a File Share on the server and copy your data from your laptop/PC to the 'drop box'. This means SQL Server only needs to open file handles to data stored locally (faster) and doesnt need continuous network files open during the import (more resilient).